# Form Validation Not Displaying on Form

Tags: django, django-views

I have a custom form validation that runs on my popup window form. If the form validation occurs i get a bad request error which is what i have programmed in my views.py . How do i render it so the user stays on the form and the validation message displays.  Thanks for the help. Here is my code.

```
@login_required
def K8_Points_Classroom(request):
    #context_from_k8_points = request.session['k8_points_context'] 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = K8Points_ClassroomForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
             form.save(commit=False)
             form.save()
             class_name = form.cleaned_data.get('class_name')
             getstudents = Student.objects.filter(class_name = class_name)
             students = getstudents.all()
             form = K8Points_ClassroomForm()
             context = {'form': form ,'students' : students, 'class_name': class_name,}
             return render(request,'points/k8_points_classroom.html', context)  

        else:
            return HttpResponseBadRequest("Bad Request")      

    else:
      return render(request, 'points/k8_points_classroom.html', {'form': form} )
```

Updated form.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% crispy K8Points_ClassroomForm %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}


<br>
<h2>{% load static %}
    <img src="{% static 'forms/star.png' %}" alt="chain" height="62" width="62">  {{class_name}}</h2>
<br>
<br>


<form action="/points/k8_points_classroom" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <!-- Start Date -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="container">
            <div class='row'>
                <div class="col-4">
                    <p> Recording Data as User : {{user.username}} </p>
                    </div>
                        </div>
                 <div class='row'>
                    <div class = "col-2">
                        {{form.date|as_crispy_field }}
                           </div>
                           <div class = "col-2">
                        {{form.week_of|as_crispy_field }}
                           </div>
                             <div class = "col-2">
                        {{form.day|as_crispy_field }}
                           </div>
                              </div>

            </div>
       </form>

            <div class="jumbotron" align="middle">
                  <img src="{% static 'forms/levelup.png' %}" alt="levelup" height="120" width= "120">
                <h1>My Students</h1>

                <!-- Line Break -->
                <hr style="border: 1px solid black;"/>
                <!-- Line Break -->

                <div class="row mb-3">
                {% for i in students%}
                        <div class="col-md-4 themed-grid-col"><h2>{{i.student_name}}</h2> 
                            <p align="left"> Today's Score: {{total}}</p>

                            <h4>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" data-toggle="modal"
                                        data-target="#PointsBox{{ student.pk }}">Level Up
                                </button>

                            </h4>
                            <div id="PointsBox{{ student.pk }}" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                                <div class="modal-dialog">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <img src="{% static 'forms/star.png' %}" align="left" alt="chain" height="42"
                                                 width="42">
                                            <h4 class="modal-title">Points Confirmation </h4>
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"> &times;</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            <h6>
                                                <div class="modal-body">Please add the selected points for the current
                                                    student.</div>
                                            </h6>



                                            <form action="/points/k8_points_classroom" method="POST">
                                                    {% csrf_token %} 
                                            <div class="form-row" align='left'>
                                                <div class="col-7">
                                                    {{form.class_name|as_crispy_field }}
                                                    <input type="student_name" class="form-control" value ="{{i}}" >
                                                    {{form.time_frame|as_crispy_field }}
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-row">
                                                <div class="col-3" align='left'>
                                                    {{form.behavior|as_crispy_field }}
                                                    {{form.academic|as_crispy_field }}

                                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ><i
                                                            class="fas fa-star"></i> Level Up
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-foot"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
     </div>
         </form>
                  {% endfor %}                           
                {% endblock %}
```

Comment: I see you've two different forms there with different data and you're sending in the context only one form (`K8Points_ClassroomForm`). If you have different forms, you'll need to create a form class for each one. The second one is in a for loop, you could add an hidden field to know which student is submitting the form. Also, take a look here, could be useful https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/11/28/advanced-form-rendering-with-django-crispy-forms.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't return a bad response if the form is invalid. Instead, render the page again with the invalid form and in the temolate you will be able to render the errors. Try starting rendering the form just using `{{ form.as_p }}` and you will see the errors. The form errors are in `form.errors` and each field has its own errors, you can access to them `form.field.erorrs`

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = K8Points_ClassroomForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
         form.save(commit=False)
         form.save()
         class_name = form.cleaned_data.get('class_name')
         getstudents = Student.objects.filter(class_name = class_name)
         students = getstudents.all()
         form = K8Points_ClassroomForm()
         context = {'form': form ,'students' : students, 'class_name': class_name,}
         return render(request,'points/k8_points_classroom.html', context)

return render(request, 'points/k8_points_classroom.html', {'form': form} )
```

Comment: so i changed the crispy form tags to {{ form.as_p }} on the whole form and im still not getting the errors displayed on the popup form. It just kicks me back to the page with no student names on them since it doesnt rereun the query.

Comment: When you submit your form the whole page will be reload even if you have errors. If you have any error the page will be reloaded but this time the form will have info in their `errors` attributes. Take a look here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/

Comment: If you changed how you render your form to {{ form.as_p }} and you still don't have the errors means that maybe your form class have something wrong. You will need to share you form code, probably your mistake is there

Comment: just posted the form html. I have a for loop that runs , the 2nd {{i.student_name }} doesnt work, only displays the first persons name of the query set on every students name.

Comment: Are you sure the other objects has `student_name`? You have another error there, but maybe you haven't see it yet. You are creating dynamically modals with the same id `id="PointsBox1"` and the id must be unique, use the `pk` of the objects to construct unique id like this: `id="PointsBox{{ student.pk }}"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203922/discussion-between-yasiel-cabrera-and-ray-zuchowski).